# UML class diagram for guest user

Tags: uml, class-diagram

The class diagram of the system i am about to sketch has two types of user, registered user and also guest user.

Is it necessary to have a guest user class in the UML?

Comment: Is the difference that registered users have an account, whereas the guest user not ?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your requirements. Either you have a simple attribute in the `User` (e.g. `isGuest`; see class right) or you create a sub-class of `User` which has different behavior (left). It's clearly a design decision.

[image]